# Will it be justifiable to use deep learning for 1-D labelled data?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm, deep-learning

I have been using SVM for training and testing one dimensional data (15000 sample points for training, 7500 sample points for testing) and it has brought up satisfactory results so far. But to improve on the results, I am thinking of using Deep Learning for the same. Will it be able to improve results? What should I study for a quick implementation of Deep Learning algorithms? I am new to the DL field but want a quick implementation, if at all it is justifiable.

Comment: A good starting point would be http://deeplearning.net/reading-list/tutorials/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In machine learning applications it is hard to say if an algorithm will improve the results or not because the results really depend on the data. There is no best algorithm. You should follow the steps given below:

- Analyze your data
- Apply the appropriate algorithms by the help of your machine learning background
- Evaluate the results

There are many machine learning libraries for different programming languages i.e. Weka for Java and scikit-learn for Python. The implementations may have special names other than the abstract names like Deep Learning. Thus, research for the implementation you are looking for in the library you are using.

Comment: Good answer. I'd just add that Deep Learning is mostly just a paradigm. Thus, the dimension of your data doesn't really matter in judging if a DL algorithm is viable or not.